# Tree view Image location for win form application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am showing the image for nodes in tree view like below, to make this work, during the run time I have to keep the image file in the application folder for the below case, is there any way to keep image in the location similar to GAC for assemblies?

```
    Dim myImageList As ImageList = New ImageList()
    myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("Tick.png"))
    TreeView1.ImageList = myImageList
    TreeView1.ImageIndex = 0
```

Comment: Why don't you add the images to your program's resources?

Comment: Okay, let me try. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your images are static and don't change after deployment, you can easily put them in a resource file. This way the images are embedded in the assembly, and easily are deployed with the application (without any extra effort).

Here is the steps to add a resource file:

In the **Solution Explorer** window, right-click on the project and select **Add->New Item**. Select **Resource File** from the shown templates and give it a name (`MyResources` for example). Click the small arrow near **Add Resource** menu above the resource window, and select **Add Existing File**. Then select your image file.

You can access the image in your code using `My.Resources.MyResources.Tick` (`Tick` is just an example image file).

Answer (score 0):

Adding it to resources solved my problem.

```
    Dim img As Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Tick.png"), Image)
    myImageList.Images.Add(img)
```

Comment: I don't know about VB, but in C# you can write `Resources.Tick` and get back an `Image`...